How to export People display name rather than string ID from sharepoint list to Excel
I'm using "Get Data" function in Excel to import a SharePoint List (an actions log).  When I import it, the action owner field (which is a "people picker", look-up field in SharePoint), only the Id  and string ID data comes through, rather than Display Name.  How do I get Display Name to import into Excel?

